# How to style the react-stripe-checkout form?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, forms, stripe-payments

I would like to know how to add custom styling to the react-stripe-checkout form component. (ex: Change the background color, etc.)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-checkout

Comment: Checkout doesn't really allow much in the style area (what you can style you can do from your Stripe dashboard https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/branding), if you want to customize things  it is best to use Elements. There's a react component for that as well https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer @duck!

Answer (score 4):

here is an example. I believe it is very clear. I use materialize css here but you can style it the way you want it.

```
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";

class Payments extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StripeCheckout
          name="survey"
          description="survey credits"
          amount={500}
          token={token => this.props.handleToken(token)}
          stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}
        >
          <button className="btn">Add Credits</button>
        </StripeCheckout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```